# Is there a way to show an enum from another model into a select picker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a little bit new to Ror. I have a relation one to one between a model 'VotationType' and 'Question'. This relation have to be polymorphical. Now i need a way that allows me to show a select picker in the question/new.html.erb that in the dropdown lists the enum_types for selecting one of them.

Model votation_type.rb

```
 class VotationType < ApplicationRecord

 belongs_to :questionable, polymorphic: true
 enum enum_type: %i[unique prioritized open_positive answer_couple answer_set]
```

Model quiestion.rb:

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord

has_one :votation_type, as: :questionable
```

The main problem of this is that i can figure it out how can i list the enum_type in the view from another model.

Answer (score 0):

Found a method that works for the moment:

```
<%= f.select :votation_type, options_for_select(VotationType.enum_types) %>
```